# Is there a way in Redux Forms to make a form validate from code?

Tags: redux-form

I'm having problems getting my code to validate on submit when the form is pristine. Is there a way to make the form validate?

Comment: See my answer to this almost identical question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40886568/how-to-re-trigger-validations-manually-in-reduxform/51065315#51065315

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.touch('username', 'email', 'age') // pass names of input fields
 }
```

Comment: The `touch` method will not run the valdation, but may unhide validation errors that were initially suppressed.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, if you're using JQuery you can create event listeners using **CSS Selectors** for the form inputs like below

```
var __inputListener__ = $("input[name=firstName]).click(function (e) {checkString(e.target.value);});

function checkString(string) {
  //Run string validation here
  if (true)
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}
```

Note, I am not sure it is `e.target.value` will return the value, you may have to `console.log(e)` to get the array of `e` and look where it is at. You just repeat this for how many inputs you want to check and etc.

EDIT:
Forgot to mention, you mean **SET** the event listeners **AFTER** the element you want it to listen to **HAS BEEN** created.