# How to re-trigger validations manually in ReduxForm?

Tags: redux-form

I like to re-trigger validations after the form has mounted. Let's assume I like to run the validations each time I click a button named 'validate inputs'.

How to do this?

Related questions:

- [How to run validation on a slice of a redux-form FieldArray state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39754558/how-to-run-validation-on-a-slice-of-a-redux-form-fieldarray-state?s=2|7.4505)
- [Is there a way in Redux Forms to make a form validate from code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39693856/is-there-a-way-in-redux-forms-to-make-a-form-validate-from-code?s=6|7.1400)

Answer (score 10):

Manual redux-form validation is an [oft](https://medium.com/@mohamedismat91/redux-form-manually-triggered-syncvalidation-with-nested-levels-b84ab611b203) [requested](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/3466) [feature](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/3992), that does not seem to be provided at the moment.

My personal workaround is to trigger `this.props.change('_validationHack', Date.now())` in the `reduxForm`-wrapped component and then remove `values._validationHack` in the `onSubmit` method before sending the `values` to the server.

It's not pretty, but seems to work without exception.

Answer (score 1):

**According to 28/11/2018:**

> https://redux-form.com/6.2.1/docs/api/actioncreators.md/

There are actions that you can dispatch for making changes to your form and triggering the validation method.

If you trigger change/touch actions it should execute the validate function.

Comment: `change`, `blur`, nor `touch` is not triggering async validation in my case. Maybe it's broken with `asyncBlurFields`?

Comment: Thank you. As my component was set up to provide errors/warns only if the field was invalid and had been "touched", then manually firing the touch action creator with the fields requiring validation did exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```js
import { touch, stopAsyncValidation } from 'redux-form';
//...
    yield put(stopAsyncValidation('CallForm', { mdn: mdn.error_message }));
    yield put(touch('CallForm', 'mdn'));
```

- clue from https://stackoverflow.com/a/51065315/588759
- clue about touch https://github.com/redux-form/redux-form/issues/3992#issuecomment-399411329
- working example https://github.com/zobroj/ab-web/blob/ea4fccb68b4f3a2f747f47d23624bc69631782ed/app/containers/RegisterPage/sagas.js#L62

  - found with https://github.com/search?l=JavaScript&q=%22yield+put%28touch%28%22&type=Code

Answer (score 0):

The sync validation is run on every render, so "triggering it" doesn't really have much meaning.

If you would like to use async validation, there is a [`this.props.asyncValidate()`](http://redux-form.com/6.2.1/docs/api/Props.md/#-asyncvalidate-function-) function that you can call to trigger it.

**OR**, if you prefer submit validation, you could just submit the form.

Comment: Thanks, @Erik. I didn't think about using submit. Will `this.props.onSubmit()` work? or should I pass the formValues as a argument?

Comment: The submit() method in instance API also seems usablel. I'll try them out first and report back.

Comment: Correction: Sync validation is *not* run on every render - so the question is very much meaningful.

Comment: this.props.asyncValidate()  did nothing