# How do I access the function, props.change()?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form, redux-form-validators

I would like to use the answer suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51065315/9973545 which involves doing

```
this.props.change('_validationHack', Date.now())
```

"in the reduxForm-wrapped component". My `this.props` has no `change` function in it, though.

I'm attempting to access the function from inside my `render` function which (heavily pared down) says something like:

```
render() {
    return (<button title="Hello, World" type="Submit" 
          onMouseDown={() => this.props.change('_validationHack', Date.now())}
          onClick={(event) => doWork(event)}
          id="my-button">
              my-button
    </button>)
}
```

I assume I'm using the wrong props, but I'm not sure what other props I have. Or perhaps I need to use another library to further decorate my props?

Comment: I think you can use [PropTypes](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html), it will help you to validate what props you require in your component and it will display a console error if there's something that you're not passing.

Comment: You need to share more code to help us to understand the context in which the component is created

Comment: Could you share example on http://codesandbox.io/?

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. In case it's not painfully obvious, I'm a react noob, so I wasn't able even to articulate the question very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The context in which I was making the call was incorrect, so I didn't have access to the `change` function. Instead, I wound up passing an helper function, `prepareValidate`, to the component so that change could be called in a parent context.